# Symfony 3.x - using entity getId() method on submitted form data object returns object (not integer)

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am trying to create a filter form with multiple fields, and one of them is a select/drop-down for selecting from a list of Tournaments.

The idea is to make the form reusable so I'm creating a FilterType form class. The Tournament select field is created by embedding a TournamentChoiceType form class which creates an EntityType field using the Tournament entity.

The issue I'm facing is when the form is submitted and I get the submitted data. The $tournamentChoice is a Tournament object (which is OK), but $tournamentId = $tournamentChoice->getId() is returning a Tournament object too, and it should be an integer (the ID columnn).

The mess seems to happen here:

```
$filterForm->handleRequest($request);
```

because when I view/dump the raw POST request all seems normal and the **filter[tournament][id]** is just an integer parameter passed in, as expected.

Here's the code.

Controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$tournamentSelected = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Tournament')
        -> findOneById($id);
$tournamentsList = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Tournament')
        ->findAll();

$formInputData = array();
$formInputData['tournament']['data'] = $tournamentSelected;
$formInputData['tournament']['choices'] = $tournamentsList;
formData = array();

$filterForm = $this->createForm(FilterType::class, $formData, array(
    'data' => $formInputData
));

$filterForm->handleRequest($request);

if ($filterForm->isSubmitted() && $filterForm->isValid()) {
    $formData = $filterForm->getData();

    $tournamentChoice = $formData['tournament'];
    $tournamentId = $tournamentChoice->getId();
    $dateFromChoice = $formData['date_from'];
    $dateToChoice = $formData['date_to'];

    return $this->redirectToRoute(
        'index',
        array('tournament' => $tournamentId)
    );
}
```

FilterType form class:

```
class FilterType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $data;

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->data = $options['data'];

        ...

        $builder
            ->add('tournament', TournamentChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => $this->data['tournament']['choices'],
                'data' => $this->data['tournament']['data']
            ))
        ;

        ...
    }
}
```

TournamentChoiceType form class:

```
class TournamentChoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $data;
    protected $choices;

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Tournament',
            'choices' => null
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->data = $options['data'];
        $this->choices = $options['choices'];

        $builder
            ->add('id', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'MyBundle:Tournament',
                'choices' => $this->choices,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'label' => false,
                'data' => $this->data
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

Tournament entity class:

```
class Tournament
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    ...
}
```

Here's how `var_dump($filterForm->getData())` looks like, after a submit:

```
array (size=4)
  'field1' => string 'text' (length=4)
  'field2' => string 'text' (length=4)
  ...
  'tournament' => 
    object(MyBundle\Entity\Tournament)[631]
      private 'id' => 
        object(MyBundle\Entity\Tournament)[522]
          private 'id' => int 11
          private 'name' => string 'tournament1' (length=11)
          private ...
          ...
```

and here's how `var_dump($filterForm->getData())` looks like, after a second submit:

```
array (size=4)
  'field1' => string 'text' (length=4)
  'field2' => string 'text' (length=4)
  ...
  'tournament' => 
    object(MyBundle\Entity\Tournament)[513]
      private 'id' => 
        &object(MyBundle\Entity\Tournament)[513]
      private 'name' => string 'tournament1' (length=11)
      private ...
```

What's with the object's ID being an object (and not being just an interger), or referencing an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by double data insertion. You have to refactor your code to set the data only once.

Firstly you set it here:

`$formInputData['tournament']['data'] = $tournamentSelected;`

Secondly if there is any request, then you set it again here:

`$filterForm->handleRequest($request);`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I didn't realize at all that the `$filterForm->handleRequest($request)` automatically populates the default data for the submitted form. So when I have a POST request, I don't need to pass the default data with `$formInputData['tournament']['data'] = $tournamentSelected`. The problem was resolved by adding this check: `$formInputData['tournament']['data'] = ($request->request->get('filter')) ? null : $tournamentSelected`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I believe in your controller you need to change this:

from:

```
$tournamentChoice = $formData['tournament'];
```

to:

```
$tournamentChoice = $formData['tournament']['choices'];
```

Try it. Otherwise you need to post more of your code in the controller. In particular how you create the `$formInputData` array.

Edit #2.
On now seeing the rest of your controller code, I now sees what's going on. You need to get the form data like so:

```
$formData = $filterForm->get("tournament")->getData();
```

This gets an array of results, so then you need to do a foreach (or similar). This is because when you created $tournamentList, you did it like this:

```
$tournamentsList = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Tournament')->findAll();
```

Comment: I've added the code you requested in the controller. But $formData['tournament']['choices'] is not possible because $formData['tournament'] is an object, not an array.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but no effect.
What `$filterForm->get("tournament")->getData()` does is that you only get the data from the 'tournament' field, and lose all of the form's other fields data. But the 'tournament' data is still an object referencing an object.
Here's how `var_dump($filterForm->getData())` looks like:

Comment: continued from the previous comment, the code extract:
`array (size=4)
  ...
  'tournament' => 
    object(MyBundle\Entity\Tournament)[631]
      private 'id' => 
        object(MyBundle\Entity\Tournament)[522]
          private 'id' => int 11
          private 'name' => string 'tournament1' (length=11)
          ...`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. $formData is a result set of Tournament object. To get individual results you need to use for in TWIG (or similar with foreach in PHP). For example: `foreach ( $formData as $tourn) { $tourn->getId(); }` or in TWIG: ` {% for t in formData %}  Tournament ID is: {{ t.getId }}  {% endfor %}`.  It appears you may not be very familiar with Symfony --> Is my presumption correct?

Comment: You are quite right, I'm new to Symfony and been using it for about a month. However, there is no point in doing `foreach ( $formData as $tourn)` because `$formData` is an array of different types of fields. Also, I cannot understand why you mention TWIG at all - I have a problem in my controller code and TWIG is used in the view templates.